# Put value of a field other than ID from list to set

Tags: apex, query, database, id, set

Below trick works for only ID field, but if I need a field other than ID field?

```
List<SObject> results = Database.query(someSOQL);
Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(results)).keySet();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write the loop yourself e.g.:

```
Set<String> s = new Set<String>();
for (SObject sob : Database.query(someSOQL)) s.add((String) sob.get(someField));
```

Comment: I need to skip for loop here.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner The "trick" you illustrate involves a loop, its just implemented in the Map constructor rather than in your own Apex. Only way I know to avoid the loop is to change to an aggregate query and so use "group by" to identify the unique values.

Comment: There will be a semicolon?                                                                                              s.add((String) ; sob.get(someField));

Comment: @SFDC_Learner No that is a cast to convert the base `Object` type that `get` returns  to the `String`  type that the `Set` requires in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I'll preface this by saying that the following is a hack (at least in my eyes). It takes advantage of how Salesforce implemented the Map constructor which accepts a list. This is only useful in a limited number of situations.

Iterating over the results of your query in a loop, and building the map yourself is generally the way to go (as Keith C mentioned).

That said, the following will work

```
Map<String, AggregateResult> testMap = new Map<String, AggregateResult>(
    [SELECT Name Id FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Name LIMIT 10]
);
```

By using `GROUP BY`, we can alias fields in the `SELECT` clause. The Map constructor looks for a field named 'Id' in the objects returned by a query. If we alias a field being used in the `GROUP BY` to `Id`, the Map constructor will use it to populate the keys of the map.

A consequence of using `GROUP BY` is that the query will return a `List<AggregateResult>` instead of a `List<sObject>`. The only fields you'll be able to grab in your query are ones that can be grouped, and results from aggregate functions (SUM(), COUNT(), MAX(), etc...)